# After a recent OSX update, my macbook pro is crashing multiple times daily

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Here is the panic report. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this? Thanks!

```
Anonymous UUID:       86B3E260-3B13-5D61-522E-F58171374B06

Wed May  3 19:43:08 2017

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000001000c07
 family: 6 model: 61 stepping: 4 microcode: 33
 signature: 0x306d4
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
 7 error-reporting banks
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801ec01d15): "Machine Check at 0xffffff801ec14f1b, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00000cd07b5ef8ac, CR3: 0x0000000022383000, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000060, RBX: 0xffffff801f293740, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff912bebbee0, RBP: 0xffffff912bebbf20, RSI: 0x0000000000000010, RDI: 0xffffff801f208e20\n" "R8:  0x0000000000000004, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000003, R11: 0x0000000000000008\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000060, R13: 0x0000000000000003, R14: 0x000021e1d81c0a28, R15: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff801ec14f1b, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.51.2/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81206dde90 : 0xffffff801eaec3ec 
0xffffff81206ddf10 : 0xffffff801ec01d15 
0xffffff81206de070 : 0xffffff801ea9dddf 
0xffffff912bebbf20 : 0xffffff801ec03010 
0xffffff912bebbf40 : 0xffffff801eb0943d 
0xffffff912bebbf90 : 0xffffff801eb09a20 
0xffffff912bebbfb0 : 0xffffff801ea9a8f7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16E195

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 06F94FD7-451F-34A1-B13C-D68FF7EDE0A0
Kernel slide:     0x000000001e800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801ea00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801e900000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 37254577028474
last loaded kext at 37245626159793: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa1b94000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 30861640567665: com.parallels.kext.hypervisor 12.2.0 41591 (addr 0xffffff7fa1ba5000, size 217088)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   92
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.14.41
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.4f18
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.59.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.14
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 404.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.50.19
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 114
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1150.9.1a2
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   5.0.4f18
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.4f18
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.41
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    311.11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.41
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   514.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    514.10
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  131.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540.30.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   199
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.14
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.16
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B24, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474346000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474346000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.124.1a2)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.4f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: Is there anything you've identified that will trigger the crash? Or does it appear totally intermittent?

Comment: First few times it happened. I was in Adobe Illustrator. Now, it just occurs completely at random. That last panic happened when I woke the system from sleep. External monitor went black and macbook screen froze. I had to do a hard reset.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with the same build! It crashed 7 times in under 16 hours, and hasn't crashed since. How long has yours been crashing? Lol once it crashed so hard the crash log didn't include anything after the kernel version.

Answer (score 3):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination and usually requires some patience.

To start with I would boot your Mac into Safe Mode and determine if it still crashes.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. does it still crash while in Safe Mode)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Test again to see if it still crashes when booted normally

Once you've booted into Safe Mode, let me know how you went and we'll go from there.

Comment: It doesn't really crash at any specific time.. It's just random.. This last time I only had sublime, iterm, and few chrome tabs open. --thanks for your help!

Comment: I would test it in Safe Mode as per my answer. However, if it crashes while in Safe Mode, I would also repeat the Safe Mode test without your MBP connected to any other devices (i.e. no external display, no USB keyboard, etc) and then report back.

Answer (score 2):

Why not back up your files and erase install OS X.

- If it doesn't crash - it was software.
- If it does crash - it's hardware.

If it's software, bring back either a user folder or apps - test. Then bring back the other - test.

Most of the time the clean install and then migrating back apps and settings and user data resolves panics that follow an update of the OS. More rarely, it's hardware in general. Most rarely, it's hardware connected and relating to the specific update.